# QEMU Guest using huge amounts of compressed memory on boot

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, virtual-memory

Virt Manager configuration:

[image]

Guest memory usage right after booting (nothing is running):
[image]

I'm running `virt-manager` on a standard Ubuntu 17.10 system. In Proxmox, the same general configuration (with ballooning enabled) would allocate `8GB` of the host but the guest would have roughly `1-2GB` used out of `16GB` instead of this.

I'm pretty sure I have all the guest drivers installed. (qemu guest, virtio stuff, balloon driver & service)

This is not my first QEMU VM, but the only one outside of Proxmox (which I'm assuming does some extra stuff that virt-manager doesn't).

What really exacerbates this issue is if I set the **Current allocation** to `2GB`, the guest has about `15.6GB` compressed and most software won't launch or run correctly because there's no free system memory...

---

Host:

```
:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32163       20273        8949         176        2940       11325
Swap:          2047           2        2045
```

[image]

Hardly anything is running on the host. It looks like the entire `16GB` is getting claimed but simultaneously most of that memory is inaccessible to the guest.

Comment: Could you please post `free -m` output from the guest and also the guest XML deffinition file (virtual HW...).

Comment: Not sure where the configuration is saved. Guest is Windows 10 so `free -m` isn't recognized. Appended host's `free -m`.

Comment: What do you mean by "compressed"? That word doesn't make sense in the context you've used it.

Comment: @Jaroslav Kucera: This is a Windows guest, `free -m` is a Linux command, am I missing something? You wrote to run it in the guest?

Comment: Re-read the first 2 comments here which should clarify what happened and why. I've since transferred this windows VM guest to bare metal and no longer have this issue.

Comment: memory committed to guests can only be used by guests, if a guest is asked to balloon, its operating system marks that memory as in-use until the balloon driver allows it to use that memory again, if there is no other guest who wants to use that memory, nobody can use it, not the host, not the guest.  This was designed to let guests trade memory when the system is over committed, and isn't very useful if the host isn't out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

usual and expected behaviour.
qemu/kvm allocates the max ram until balloon service is started.
afterwards any ram consumed by balloon service is free (from host pov)

Comment: Yes, but there are committed 10GB! One(me at least) would expect this to be 1-2GB. But when you set max higher than current you get this strange behaviour. Looking for an answer on another [thread] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534679/strange-memory-allocation-in-w10-kvm-guest-using-balloon-memory)

Comment: ...and I mean those 10GB will stay like that,  it's not just right after boot (at least that's what I see on my system).