# Strange memory allocation in W10 KVM guest using balloon memory

Tags: windows, memory, kvm, qemu

My Win10 guest use 3.2GB when it just booted when setting a low "CurrentMemroy" in then KVM/QEMU virt-config-XML file for the guest:

```
<memory unit='GiB'>4</memory>
<currentMemory unit='GiB'>2</currentMemory>
```

Confirming allocated memory to the guest by the host:

```
virsh qemu-monitor-command --hmp W10x 'info balloon'
balloon: actual=2048
```

Windows' committed memory is very high (never seen so high on a new booted W10)
[image]

Now to the funny part, I'll increase the allocated memory for the guest to 4GB:

```
virsh qemu-monitor-command --hmp W10x 'balloon 4096'
virsh qemu-monitor-command --hmp W10x 'info balloon'
balloon: actual=4096
```

[image]

Can any one explain this behaviour, I would expect the opposite behaviour?

I would prefer to just allocated 2GB at boot and then increase if needed (will also try to play around with the auto-allocation), but now I'm afraid I'll have a bad running guests with this configuration?
Did try to load a lot of pages in Chrome, seems to run fine though. But it's hard to tell with those speedy NVMe's :-P

And using memory=2GB & currentMemmory=2GB I get the expected result:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're asking about the behaviour of Windows 10.

Comment: This is the behaviour of the memory Balloon driver, which is a component of KVM/QEMU. This driver handle the memory management in quests. This topic has nothing to do with a "normal" Windows installation, but only virtualized Windows clients and severs and therefore very much related to Linux KVM virtualization.

Comment: that's an interesting assertion.  to prove it, you'd have to show that VMs running Linux or *BSD or other operating systems exhibited the same behaviour.

Comment: Or you'd have to show a Windows exhibited the same behaviour not running on a Linux KVM host server ;-) It's obvious also related to Windows, but saying it not related to Linux and KVM is not true.

Comment: either way, your question is *still* about the behaviour of **Windows**.  This site is for questions about unix or linux, not Windows.   If you want to know about the behaviour of Windows, ask on the generic https://superuser.com/ or on some windows-specific site.

Comment: This is a question for KVM/QEMU administrators about the KVM/QEMU balloon Driver which is used on "all" guest OSs, and assumably works be the same principles in all of them. And "Unix & Linux" is the closet forum I could pick for this subject and the forum with best change to find a KVM/QEMU administrator who have an answer. It's a shame there's not a forum for virtualization on SE, that would be great.

Comment: I'm having the issue and I think this is an appropriate place for this question.

Comment: I now realized it's not really optimized for Windows and should not be used with Windows guest, that also the official statement (sorry, have no link)